# How do I get the sum based on selected radio button only?

Tags: jquery, input, sum, radio-button

I have a form in which I want to collect my output
This form is displayed in a table where there are 2 options to choose from in each row
The problem with my code is that both buttons add up but I need to add one of them

Here is my code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).on("change", ".qty1", function() {
      var sum = 0;
      $(".qty1").each(function(){
          sum += +$(this).val();
      });
      $(".total").val(sum);
  });

</script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="qty1" type="radio" name="product_1" value="123" /></td>
    <td><input class="qty1" type="radio" name="product_1" value="234" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="qty1" type="radio" name="product_2" value="123" /></td>
    <td><input class="qty1" type="radio" name="product_2" value="234" /></td>
  </tr>  
</table>

<input class="total" type="text" name="" value="">
```

Comment: "_The problem with my code is that both buttons add up but I need to add one of them_" how to decide which one to add from each row?

Comment: @palaѕн From their name att

Comment: But there are two elements with same name in each row.

Comment: @palaѕн How can I separate rows? Is it possible to do it with id?

Comment: Each row is for one product and the price is for 2 packages. I put same name to let the users just choose one of them

Comment: Ok, then your question actually is how to get the sum based on selected radio button only, right?

Comment: @palaѕн Exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the sum based on the selected radio button, you can simply loop through the `checked` radio buttons instead of looping through all elements with class `.qty1` like:

```js
$(document).on("change", ".qty1", function() {
  var sum = 0;
  $(".qty1:checked").each(function() {
    sum += +$(this).val();
  });
  $(".total").val(sum);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="qty1" type="radio" name="product_1" value="123" />123</td>
    <td><input class="qty1" type="radio" name="product_1" value="234" />234</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="qty1" type="radio" name="product_2" value="123" />123</td>
    <td><input class="qty1" type="radio" name="product_2" value="234" />234</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<input class="total" type="text" name="" value="">
```